# How to limit mod_rewrite to a single directory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to enable permalinks in wordpress. My wordpress blog sits on **domain.com/blog**.

I know I need to add the following to my `apache.conf` (edit: as also achieved via settings->permalinks in the wp admin console) :

```
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

However, I am already using the following rewrite expressions for the rest of my site:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$       http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If I add the wordpress settings, then these others are overwritten. How can I preserve these settings and still apply the wordpress permalink settings to my blog subdir? I'd like to do this with `apache.conf` and not `.htaccess`.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you change the permalinks in wordpress itself in `Settings -> Permalinks`?

Comment: @Howlin this is exactly that; the code here shows precisely what that option in wordpress settings attempts to do. It creates the conflict as I am already using rewrite expressions as shown.